# Difference between different datasources

Tags: sql-server

Him
Please explain what is the difference between different datasources for SQL (shown in the pic.)

I mean difference between Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft SQL Server Database File

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server means that you are establishing a network connection to a SQL Server -- the database engine is running either on your machine or remotely and you are using the SQL Server as a service and are connecting to it.  That server has the data and you just use a protocol to request operations to be performed.

Connecting using a Microsoft SQL Server database file (MDF) means that you want to use a database file and have a running SQL Server engine running locally use that MDF file.  So, if you have SQL Express on your machine, when you create a connection to a MDF file, you're essentially using the SQLExpress engine on your machine to serve up that MDF file (and the database contents) to you.

I admit I almost always connect to a SQL Server, as I'm not guaranteed to have the MDF file available in all environments.  Plus, I usually don't install SQL Express.

That's how I understand the difference.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the "Microsoft SQL Server Database File" option refers to manually using SQL Server's files (*.MDF), whereas the Microsoft SQL Server refers to connecting to a full-blown SQL Server ?